# Is there any way to fix E_FAIL (0x80004005)?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I URGENTLY need help because I have an assignment due tonight. Thank you in advance!

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine myMachine.

Could not open the medium 'C:\Users\...\Snapshots/{2e933747-5235-41f1-8ba8-c6368a235243}.vhd'.

VD: Image file 'C:\Users\...\Snapshots/{2e933747-5235-41f1-8ba8-c6368a235243}.vhd' is corrupted and can't be opened (VERR_VD_IMAGE_CORRUPTED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
```

I realize this question has been asked before [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1425610/virtualbox-fails-to-load-vm-with-code-e-fail-0x80004005), but I tried running `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` then `sfc /scannow`, but it didn't help. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox, but it didn't help. I also disabled Hyper-V through the Control Panel and ran Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor in the powershell

Host: Windows 10 Pro: Version 10.0.19042 
 Virtual Machine: Debian Linux (Version 10)

Comment: [Edit] your question to indicate what version of VirtualBox you are running.  **Hyper-V isn't even a component of Windows 7 and cannot be enabled on any edition.**  If you are not actually using Windows 7 you should edit the tags and mention which version of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using Windows 10 Pro: Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042 and the Virtual machine is running Debian 10 (64-bit)

Comment: This isn't a system configuration error, the error specifically is indicating, the file `{2e933747-5235-41f1-8ba8-c6368a235243}.vhd` is corrupt.  `0x80004005` return code is used when VirtualBox encounters a issue with a file.

Comment: [This](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=84332) explains your current problem.  Since one of your snapshots are corrupt there really isn't a solution to your problem other than recreating the VM.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dir /s "C:\Users\...\Snapshots/"` and the relevant information about the snapshots from within the .`.vbox` file for the virtual machine.  You can do that by doing the following: `Right-click on the VM in the VirtualBox Manager, select "Show in Explorer"` Please provide the relevant xml node that indicates which snapshot belongs to `{2e933747-5235-41f1-8ba8-c6368a235243}.vhd`

Comment: I found the file, but how do I get "the relevant xml node"?

Comment: It's an xml file.  You open it up in notepad

Answer (score 1):

> I URGENTLY need help because I have an assignment due tonight. Thank you in advance!

You most likely have to create a new virtual machine and install Debian on it.  One of your snapshots for the Virtual Machine is corrupt.  `{2e933747-5235-41f1-8ba8-c6368a235243}.vhd` is likely 0 KB, if that is the case, there isn't any solution to your problem.  You can try to delete the corrupt snapshot from the snapshot chain.

Your issue is best explained by the following:

> When a virtual disk is first created for a new virtual machine, it is
> considered as the base disk for the guest - data for the guest is read
> from and written to that disk image.
>
> The differencing disk records changes sector-by-sector to the whole
> disk image, not changes to any file in the disk. VirtualBox does not
> know what file system is employed on the disk image and therefore can
> not access any individual file of/on the disk image; only the guest OS
> is aware of that information.
>
> First Snapshot creates a differencing disk for read/write access while
> the base disk becomes read-only - as the guest modifies its data, the
> data is written to the differencing disk and the base disk is
> untouched.
>
> Second Snapshot creates another, new, differencing disk for read/write
> access while the first differencing disk becomes read-only along with
> the base disk.
>
> Subsequent Snapshots create additional differencing disks, with the
> preceding differencing disk joining the hierarchy (pecking
> order/chain) of read-only disks.
>
> Keep in mind that access to/from the virtual disks is
> sector-by-sector, not file-by-file.
>
> When the guest requests that a sector be read, the latest Snapshot is
> read first. If the sector is not found there (Sector-Not-Found is
> returned), the next Snapshot in the chain (youngest to oldest) is
> read, until the base virtual disk is reached. Then the sector on/in
> the base virtual disk is either read or Sector-Not-Found is returned.
>
> [image]
>
> I've marked the changes from "Snapshot 2" (the "B" sectors) differently for a reason. Say that you go outside of VirtualBox and you delete "Snapshot 2". Or the file gets corrupted, truncated or somehow modified. And then you try to recreate your hard drive. With all the "B" sectors missing that would be an impossibility.
>
> People often confuse that a "Snapshot" is and what the "HD state" is. They think that when they're taking a snapshot they take a differential backup of the files and if they delete a snapshot manually they can recover from it. No.
> [image]

Sources:

- [Snapshot basics](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=84332)
- [Error When i opened Virtual machine](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=95430)